# while running the selenium test case in azure devops getting below errors

Tags: selenium, testing, cucumber, azure-pipelines, ui-automation

Issue 1:

```
The driver executable does not exist: Java.lang.IllegalStateException:The driver executable does not exists : c:\Tools\Cucumber Application\cucumberForAppian-21.1\lib\drivers\chromedriver.exe
D:\a\1\s\src\test\resources\Drivers\chromedriver.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error presented there is no `chromedriver.exe` in `c:\Tools\Cucumber Application\cucumberForAppian-21.1\lib\drivers\` folder

Comment: Chromedriver.exe is present on the above path however locally my code is working but through azure pipeline i am facing this error.

Comment: If so there is a problem with some settings. You did not provide any information so it's impossible to know where is it comes from

Comment: What information will be needed please let me know to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is extremely short but I am going to guess.

You need to have the chromedriver also in the Azure DevOps available. This chromedriver needs to be compatible with the agent you use in the pipeline. If you use e.g. `vmImage: ubuntu-latest` you need to have the chromedriver for linux available.

It looks like you have checked in the chromedriver in your repository, you would need to do that also with the linux version and set it in the system properties.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "test/resources/Drivers/chromedriver");
```

If you go with another windows based agent `vmImage: windows-latest`, you still need to refer to the chromedriver.exe in the system properties.